# ThreadPoolExecutor multiprocessing with while loop and breadth first search?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, breadth-first-search, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to speed up some API calls by using `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I have a class that accepts a string list of [h3 cells](https://wolf-h3-viewer.glitch.me/) like `cell1,cell2`. h3 uses hexagons at different resolutions to get finer detail in mapping. The class methods take the returned cells and gets information about them that is passed to an API with params. The API will return a total number of results (could be over 1000). Because the API is limited to returning at most the first 1000 results through pagination, I utilize h3 to zoom into each cell until all of its children/grandchildren/etc have a total number of results under 1000. This is effectively doing BFS from the original cells provided.

When running this code with the `run` method, the expectation is that the `search_queue` would be empty as all cells have been processed. However, with the way its set up currently, only the `origin_cells` provided to the class get processed and retrieving `search_queue` shows unprocessed items. Swapping the `while` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` lines does run everything as expected, but it runs at the same speed as without using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Is there a way to make the multiprocessing work as expected?

Edit with working example

```py
import h3
import math
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

dummy_results = {
    '85489e37fffffff': {'total': 1001},
    '85489e27fffffff': {'total': 999},
    '86489e347ffffff': {'total': 143},
    '86489e34fffffff': {'total': 143},
    '86489e357ffffff': {'total': 143},
    '86489e35fffffff': {'total': 143},
    '86489e367ffffff': {'total': 143},
    '86489e36fffffff': {'total': 143},
    '86489e377ffffff': {'total': 143},
}

class SearchH3Test(object):

    def __init__(self, origin_cells):
        self.search_queue = list(filter(None, origin_cells.split(',')))
        self.params_list = []
        
    def get_h3_radius(self, cell, buffer=False):
        """
        Get the approximate radius of the h3 cell
        """
        return math.ceil(
            math.sqrt(
                (h3.cell_area(cell))/(1.5*math.sqrt(3))
            )*1000
            + ((100*(h3.h3_get_resolution(cell)/10)) if buffer else 0)
        )
    
    def get_items(self, cell):
        """
        Return API items from passed params, including total number of items and a dict of items

        r = requests.get(
            url = 'https://someapi.com',
            headers = api_headers,
            params = params
        ).json()
        """
        sleep(1)

        r = dummy_results[cell]

        return r['total']
    
    def get_hex_params(self, cell):
        """
        Return results from the derived params of the h3 cell
        """
        lat, long = h3.h3_to_geo(cell)
        radius = self.get_h3_radius(cell, buffer=True)

        params = {
            'latitude': lat,
            'longitude': long,
            'radius': radius,
        }

        total = self.get_items(cell)
        print(total)

        return total, params
    
    def hex_search(self):
        """
        Checks if the popped h3 cell produces a total value over 1000.
        If over 1000, get the h3 cell children and append them to the search_queue
        If greater than 0, append params to params_list
        """
        cell = self.search_queue.pop(0)
        total, params = self.get_hex_params(cell)
        if total > 1000:
            self.search_queue.extend(list(h3.h3_to_children(cell)))
        elif total > 0:
            self.params_list.append(params)
    
    def get_params_list(self):
        """
        Keep looping through the search quque until no items remain.
        Use multiprocessing to speed up things
        """
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
            while self.search_queue:
                e.submit(self.hex_search)
    
    def run(self):
        self.get_params_list()
```

```
h = SearchH3Test(
    '85489e37fffffff,85489e27fffffff',
)

h.run()
len(h.search_queue) # returns 7 for the children that weren't processed as expected
len(h.params_list) # returns 1 for the cell under 1000
```

Comment: Further research seems to point to concurrent.futures not playing nicely with changing iterators. In my case, I don't know the full list of things to be processed, so I need to add to the queue list as I'm going along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with multiple threads/process, you must use a queue data structure, which is thread safe. Here is my rewrite of your code:

```py
import math
import queue
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import h3

dummy_results = {
    "85489e37fffffff": {"total": 1001},
    "85489e27fffffff": {"total": 999},
    "86489e347ffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e34fffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e357ffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e35fffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e367ffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e36fffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e377ffffff": {"total": 143},
}


class SearchH3Test:
    def __init__(self, origin_cells):
        self.search_queue = queue.Queue()
        for cell in origin_cells.split(","):
            if cell:
                self.search_queue.put(cell)
        self.params_list = queue.Queue()

    def get_h3_radius(self, cell, buffer=False):
        """
        Get the approximate radius of the h3 cell
        """
        return math.ceil(
            math.sqrt((h3.cell_area(cell)) / (1.5 * math.sqrt(3))) * 1000
            + ((100 * (h3.h3_get_resolution(cell) / 10)) if buffer else 0)
        )

    def get_items(self, cell):
        """
        Return API items from passed params, including total number of items and a dict of items

        r = requests.get(
            url = 'https://someapi.com',
            headers = api_headers,
            params = params
        ).json()
        """
        result = dummy_results[cell]
        return result["total"]

    def get_hex_params(self, cell):
        """
        Return results from the derived params of the h3 cell
        """
        lat, long = h3.h3_to_geo(cell)
        radius = self.get_h3_radius(cell, buffer=True)

        params = {
            "latitude": lat,
            "longitude": long,
            "radius": radius,
        }

        total = self.get_items(cell)
        print(f"{total=}")

        return total, params

    def hex_search(self):
        """
        Checks if the popped h3 cell produces a total value over 1000.
        If over 1000, get the h3 cell children and append them to the search_queue
        If greater than 0, append params to params_list
        """
        try:
            cell = self.search_queue.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            return

        total, params = self.get_hex_params(cell)
        if total > 1000:
            for children in h3.h3_to_children(cell):
                self.search_queue.put(children)
        elif total > 0:
            self.params_list.put(params)

    def get_params_list(self):
        """
        Keep looping through the search quque until no items remain.
        Use multiprocessing to speed up things
        """
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            while not self.search_queue.empty():
                executor.submit(self.hex_search)

    def run(self):
        self.get_params_list()


    def debug_print(self):
        print()
        print("search_queue:")
        temp_queue = queue.Queue()
        while not self.search_queue.empty():
            element = self.search_queue.get()
            print(f"  {element}")
            temp_queue.put(element)
        self.search_queue = temp_queue

        temp_queue = queue.Queue()
        print("params_list:")
        while not self.params_list.empty():
            param = self.params_list.get()
            print(f"  {param}")
            temp_queue.put(param)
        self.params_list = temp_queue
        print()


h = SearchH3Test(
    "85489e37fffffff,85489e27fffffff",
)
h.debug_print()
h.run()
h.debug_print()
```

Here is the output:

```
search_queue:
  85489e37fffffff
  85489e27fffffff
params_list:

total=1001
total=999
total=143
total=143
total=143
total=143
total=143
total=143
total=143

search_queue:
params_list:
  {'latitude': 30.439669178763303, 'longitude': -97.74145162032264, 'radius': 10589}
  {'latitude': 30.274024109195224, 'longitude': -97.83825545496954, 'radius': 4047}
  {'latitude': 30.32926630624169, 'longitude': -97.8060126711982, 'radius': 4046}
  {'latitude': 30.331766923236522, 'longitude': -97.73454628471268, 'radius': 4045}
  {'latitude': 30.223829096285723, 'longitude': -97.72765390431441, 'radius': 4046}
  {'latitude': 30.221311831797678, 'longitude': -97.79905214479454, 'radius': 4047}
  {'latitude': 30.276552903546015, 'longitude': -97.76681177354345, 'radius': 4046}
  {'latitude': 30.27904199229733, 'longitude': -97.69539091275956, 'radius': 4045}
```

#### Notes

- I use `queue.Queue` in place of lists for the reason stated above
- Most of the changes in the code focus on the differences between a queue and a list. For example `list.pop()` -> `queue.get()` or `queue.get_nowait()`
- I added the `debug_print()` method to aid debugging. You can remove it if no longer needed

#### Reference

- https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/queue.html

## Update

In this update, I am still using `queue.Queue()` to store data, but shift the `Queue.get()` operation from `hex_search` to `get_params_list()`.

In `get_params_list()`, I will retrieve a cell from the `self.search_queue`, but this time with a time out of 5 seconds. I also allow time out to occur 3 times before declaring a done.

Other changes includes adding some random delay to `get_items()` to simulate upstream delay. I also created a `LOGGER` object for debugging purpose. A logger is nicer than print: When all is done, I can just set the level to `logging.WARN` to turn off all the messages. Also, a logger works better with multi processing environment.

```py
import logging
import math
import queue
import random
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import h3

# Create a logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(levelname)s: %(funcName)s: %(message)s"
)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

dummy_results = {
    "85489e37fffffff": {"total": 1001},
    "85489e27fffffff": {"total": 999},
    "86489e347ffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e34fffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e357ffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e35fffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e367ffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e36fffffff": {"total": 143},
    "86489e377ffffff": {"total": 143},
}


class SearchH3Test:
    def __init__(self, origin_cells):
        self.search_queue = queue.Queue()
        for cell in origin_cells.split(","):
            if cell:
                self.search_queue.put(cell)
        self.params_list = queue.Queue()

    def get_h3_radius(self, cell, buffer=False):
        """
        Get the approximate radius of the h3 cell
        """
        return math.ceil(
            math.sqrt((h3.cell_area(cell)) / (1.5 * math.sqrt(3))) * 1000
            + ((100 * (h3.h3_get_resolution(cell) / 10)) if buffer else 0)
        )

    def get_items(self, cell):
        """
        Return API items from passed params, including total number of items and a dict of items

        r = requests.get(
            url = 'https://someapi.com',
            headers = api_headers,
            params = params
        ).json()
        """
        # Simulate some random delay
        delay = random.randint(1, 10)
        LOGGER.debug("Delay for %d second(s)", delay)
        time.sleep(delay)
        result = dummy_results[cell]
        return result["total"]

    def get_hex_params(self, cell):
        """
        Return results from the derived params of the h3 cell
        """
        lat, long = h3.h3_to_geo(cell)
        radius = self.get_h3_radius(cell, buffer=True)

        params = {
            "latitude": lat,
            "longitude": long,
            "radius": radius,
        }

        total = self.get_items(cell)
        LOGGER.debug("total=%d", total)

        return total, params

    def hex_search(self, cell):
        """
        Checks if the popped h3 cell produces a total value over 1000.
        If over 1000, get the h3 cell children and append them to the search_queue
        If greater than 0, append params to params_list
        """
        total, params = self.get_hex_params(cell)
        if total > 1000:
            for children in h3.h3_to_children(cell):
                self.search_queue.put(children)
        elif total > 0:
            self.params_list.put(params)

    def get_params_list(self):
        """
        Keep looping through the search quque until no items remain.
        Use multiprocessing to speed up things
        """
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            timeout_count = 0
            while timeout_count < 3:
                try:
                    cell = self.search_queue.get(timeout=5)
                    executor.submit(self.hex_search, cell)
                except queue.Empty:
                    timeout_count += 1

    def run(self):
        self.get_params_list()


    def debug_print(self):
        LOGGER.debug("search_queue:")
        temp_queue = queue.Queue()
        while not self.search_queue.empty():
            element = self.search_queue.get()
            LOGGER.debug("  %s", element)
            temp_queue.put(element)
        LOGGER.debug("  <END>")
        self.search_queue = temp_queue

        temp_queue = queue.Queue()
        LOGGER.debug("params_list:")
        while not self.params_list.empty():
            param = self.params_list.get()
            LOGGER.debug("  %s", param)
            temp_queue.put(param)
        LOGGER.debug("  <END>")
        self.params_list = temp_queue


h = SearchH3Test(
    "85489e37fffffff,85489e27fffffff",
)
h.debug_print()
h.run()
h.debug_print()
```

Comment: Part of the issue I've run into is when there's a delay in retrieving data in any of the upstream methods. For example, I added sleep(1) to get_hex_params function and I see similar issues where the queue doesn't get fully processed.

Comment: See my update section. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I think this is getting on the right track! Is there any reasoning behind the timeout_count check being 3 and not 1 or 5 or some other number? I was doing some testing with a deeper graph and saw some cases where not every item in the search queue was processed.

Comment: No, it could be 3, or 100. As for timeout in `.get(timeout=X)`, that value depends on how long the wait is.

Comment: It looks like it would be make more sense to have `.get(timeout=X)` be a reasonable number than to have a large `timeout_count` correct? And I assume the timeout is necessary to avoid the program from running to fast?

Comment: Yes, adjusting `timeout` is more important than `timeout_count`.